# How to configure directory-recursive Sass compilation task by Grunt

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, sass, gruntjs

I'm a newbie and learning how to configure coffee, jade, and sass compilation tasks.
I could successfully configure compilation tasks for coffee and jade directory but I couldn't for sass.
The structure of my project is bellow

```
.                                                                                                   
├── Gruntfile.coffee                                                                                
├── node_modules                                                                                    
├── package.json                                                                                    
├── sass                                                                                            
│   └── index.sass                                                                                  
└── www
```

and my package.json is

```
{
  "name": "grunt-sass-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "~0.5.0"
  }
}
```

when Gruntfile.coffee is bellow, *$ grunt sass* compile index.css successfully:

```
module.exports = (grunt) ->
  grunt.initConfig
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')
    sass:
      compile:
        files:[
          "www/index.css": "sass/index.sass"
        ]
```

but when as bellow, **>> Source file "index.sass" not found.** error is shown

```
    sass:
      compile:
        cwd: 'sass'
        src: ['**/*.sass']
        dest: 'www/'
        ext: '.css'
```

How can I configure recursive sass compilation task?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In grunt all recursive files work the same way:

```
files: [{
  expand: true,
  cwd: "sass/folder",
  src: ["**/*.sass"],
  dest: "dest/folder",
  ext: ".css"
}]
```

`expand` is for doing recursive, `cwd` is startup directory, `src` is regex to match `**` (in folder), `dest` is the folder where it saves after being compiled, and finally `ext` is the extension added

This should work for all tasks which use files, in grunt.

Comment: OMG, my mistake was typo "expand" with "expnad", thank you very much.

Comment: Make sure you don't add a `/` before `sass/folder` or before `dest/folder`. For some reason it breaks it. That was issue I was having.